# Probability last draw in a negative hypergeometric experiment is first type

Tags: probability

Consider the following experiment: An urn contains a total of $N<\infty$ gems, of which $R\ge1$ gems are ruby, $G\ge1$ gems are emerald, and $N-R-G$ gems are zircon. Fix $r\in\left\{1,\ldots,R\right\}$ and $g\in\left\{1,\ldots,G\right\}$. We draw gems from the urn randomly and without replacement, stopping as soon as we have at least $r$ rubies and at least $g$ emeralds.

What is the probability that the experiment is stopped at the draw of a ruby?

Running some simulations, I have guessed that when $r=g=1$ the desired probability is $G/\left(R+G\right)$. However, for larger values of $r$ and $g$, even when $r=g$, the rule escapes me.

Comment: One thing to note is that the number of zircon gems do not affect this probability.

Comment: @Math1000 Duly noted. I included the zircons because this question relates to another question where the number of zircons is relevant, but for this question, by all means assume R+G=N.